# group operation on cartesian product transitive

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting on two sets $A$ and $B$. Then we have a natural action of $G$ on $A \times B$ given by $g.(a,b) = (g.a, g.b)$. Suppose $G$ acts transitively on $A$ and $B$. I wondered if then the following is true:

$$ G \text{ acts transitively on } A \times B \Leftrightarrow A \text{ or } B \text{ is a singleton.}
$$
The $\Leftarrow$ implication is of course trivial, but I'm stuck with the other one. I (rather naively) tried to find a contradiction when assuming that $A$ and $B$ both have more than one element, however this did not work out for me. I feel like this problem should not be too hard and I just do not see the obvious. Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Try $G=C_6$ with $|A|=2$, $|B|=3$.

Comment: In fact the condition holds whenever $|A|$ and $|B|$ are coprime, but even that is not a necessary condition.

Comment: I see. Either way, my question is thereby settled. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568117/transitive-group-action-on-two-sets-a-b-implies-transitivity-on-a-times-b).